# SvelteKit Null when access the store in function

Tags: sveltekit, svelte-component, svelte-store

I got a null value when I access a property of a store variable.

[image]

```
    <script>
    import { loadUserInfo } from '../stores/usernameStore.js';
    import { user } from '../stores/sessionStore.js';
    import { goto } from '$app/navigation';

    // let username = loadUserInfo($user.email);
    // console.log(username);

  loadUserInfo($user.id)

    function handleClick() {
        goto('/user/' + $user.id);
    }
</script>
```

Function loadUserInfo() will fail if I use any attribute of $user store variable with the above error, but function handleClick(), will work fine and redirect to the right place using the same store variable and attribute.

How is that possible what am I missing here? Cannot the store variables used a arguments on funcitons?

I'm a bit lost

```
export const loadUserInfo = async (email) => {
    const { data, error } = await supabase.from('-----').select().eq('----', email )
    if (error) {
        return console.error(error);
    }
    username.set(data);
};
```

Thanks

Comment: I think there is a lack of knowledge how async/await functions work in JavaScript. Please check your code that it is properly using async primivites.

Comment: I think you need to return the `data` value in `loadUserInfo`